# Create the setTimeout in the parent and closes it in the children

Tags: reactjs, typescript, settimeout, react-ref

I have a specific problem that is keeping me awake this whole week.

I have a parent component which has a pop-up children component. When I open the page the pop-up shows off and after 5 seconds it disappears with a `setTimeout`.

This pop-up has an input element in it.

I want the pop-up to disappear after 5 seconds or if I click to digit something in the input. I tried to create a `timerRef` to the `setTimeout` and closes it in the children but it didn't work.

Can you help me, please? Thanks in advance.

ParentComponent.tsx

```js
const ParentComponent = () => {
    const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(true)
    timerRef = useRef<ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>>()

    timerRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
        setIsVisible(false)
    }, 5000)

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => clearTimeout()
    })

    return (
        <div>
            <ChildrenComponent isVisible={isVisible} inputRef={timerRef} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

ChildrenComponent.tsx

```js
const ChildrenComponent = ({ isVisible, inputRef}) => {
    return (
        <div className=`${isVisible ? 'display-block' : 'display-none'}`>
            <form>
                <input onClick={() => clearTimeout(inputRef.current as NodeJS.Timeout)} />
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: To clarify, when they type in the input, do you want it to close immediately, or cancel the 5s timer completely?

Comment: Because of the `setTimeout` the normal behavior of the pop-up is to disappear after 5 seconds. I need to stop this behavior if the user starts to type in the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting a new timer every time the the component re-renders, aka when the state changes which happens in the timeout itself.

```js
timerRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
  setIsVisible(false);
}, 5000);
```

Instead you can put the initialization in a `useEffect`.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (timerRef.current) return;

  timerRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
    setIsVisible(false);
  }, 5000);
  return () => clearTimeout(timerRef.current);
}, []);
```

You should also **remove** the "loose" useEffect that runs on every render, this one

```js
useEffect(() => {
  return () => clearTimeout();
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I need to create the `timeRef.current` outside of `useEffect` because I need to pass it to the children component. If I create the `timeRef` inside `useEffect`I can't pass it.

Comment: It does not matter if you add the timeout value to the `timeRef.current` inside the `useEffect`, you can still pass the `timeRef.current` to the children.